# Overlap components on a page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I'm trying to get my CRA to look like this:
[image]

This is what I have so far, this:
[image]

or this:
[image]

I'm having the trouble of not being able place the map directly below background image without blocking the big information bar but the bar should actually overlap the map. Can this be done with using flexbox? If I try to absolute positioning the map it will block the big information bar. Any help would be appreciated.

My CSS, which will result in the first picture, without blocking the information bar:

```
.App {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
} 

.img {
  background-image: url('./images/pattern-bg.png');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.flexContainer {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: start;
}

.searchBar, .btn {
    margin: 40px 0px;
    border-width: 0px;
}

.searchBar {
    width: 400px;
    padding: 20px 25px;
    border-radius: 15px 0px 0px 15px;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.btn {
    padding: 21px 25px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
}

.map {
    height: 500px;
    max-height: none;
    width: 100%; 
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}

/* CSS for the big white information block */

.block {
    width: 1200px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1px solid;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.details {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.lastElem {
    border: none;
}
```

My App.js made more simple

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="img">
        <div className="flexContainer">
            <Title />
            <SearchBar />
            <InformationBlock />
            <DisplayMap />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: 1. use `position: absolute` for the bar 2. place it last in the container so it overlaps the other elements

Comment: The bar is blocked by the map if I do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by combining Chris's answer by absolutely positioning the component (but placing it above other components and elements in the container did not work for me). But I also added `z-index: 999;` to the .block className which did the trick.